# Create dynamic Word Cloud using d3.js

Tags: json, dynamic, d3.js, word-cloud

I am using the following example as base and want to make it dynamic word cloud
https://github.com/jasondavies/d3-cloud

The data is added to the array but my word-cloud is not reflecting the newly added word(s):

```
<script>
  var fill = d3.scale.category20();
  var data = [{word:"Hello",weight:20},{word:"World",weight:10},{word:"Normally",weight:25},{word:"You",weight:15},{word:"Want",weight:30},{word:"More",weight:12},{word:"Words",weight:8},{word:"But",weight:18},{word:"Who",weight:22},{word:"Cares",weight:27}];

  d3.layout.cloud().size([500, 500])
          .words(data.map(function(d) {
              return {text: d.word, size: d.weight};
          }))
          .padding(5)
         .rotate(function() { return ~~(Math.random() * 2) * 90; })
         .font("Impact")
         .fontSize(function(d) { return d.size; })
         .on("end", draw)
         .start();

  function draw(words) {
      d3.select("body").append("svg")
           .attr("width", 300)
          .attr("height", 300)
          .append("g")
          .attr("transform", "translate(150,150)")
          .selectAll("text")
          .data(words)
          .enter().append("text")
          .style("font-size", function(d) { return d.size + "px"; })
          .style("font-family", "Impact")
          .style("fill", function(d, i) { return fill(i); })
          .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
          .attr("transform", function(d) {
              return "translate(" + [d.x, d.y] + ")rotate(" + d.rotate + ")";
          })
         .text(function(d) { return d.text; });
   }

   function drawUpdate(words){
      //alert(JSON.stringify(words));   //shows me the added data

     d3.select("body").selectAll("text")
          .data(words.map(function(d) {
               return {text: d.word, size: d.weight};
          }))
          .style("font-size", function(d) { return d.size + "px"; })
          .style("font-family", "Impact")
          .style("fill", function(d, i) { return fill(i); })
          .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
          .text(function(d) { return d.text; });       
  }

 setInterval(function () { 
    var d_new = data;
    d_new.push({word: "Mappy",weight:35});
     drawUpdate(d_new);
 }, 1500);

</script>
```

Also, it refreshed the first time, but without the new word added. Could someone please rectify or point out what am I doing wrong in this.
Thanks

Comment: You are not handling the enter selection (that would contain the new word) in your update function.

Comment: But when I add enter() in the drawUpdate function after data(), it gives me undefined is not a function error in browser console. Can you please elaborate

Comment: The code would look the same as in your `draw()` function.

Comment: Thanks Lars it working somewhat, but the added words are showing on the same position overlapping the previous one. Any ideas on that?

Comment: You also have to update the positions of the existing words like you're doing already. Save the selection in a variable after calling `.data()` and then get the enter and update selections from it.

Comment: I tried using the transform attr inside the update function, but it is giving d.x as undefined, cannot understand this behaviour as same syntax is working for draw function. Why can't it find the x,y cordinates in the second function with the same data set?

Comment: You also need to pass the new data to the cloud layout again.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks to Larks I was able to get it done. Here I am sharing the code if anyone else faces a similar issue, I hope it can help

```
<script>

var fill = d3.scale.category20();
  var data = [{word:"Hello",weight:20},{word:"World",weight:10},{word:"Normally",weight:25},{word:"You",weight:15},{word:"Want",weight:30},{word:"More",weight:12},{word:"Words",weight:8},{word:"But",weight:18},{word:"Who",weight:22},{word:"Cares",weight:27}];

d3.layout.cloud().size([500, 500])
      .words(data.map(function(d) {
        return {text: d.word, size: d.weight};
      }))
      .padding(5)
      .rotate(function() { return ~~(Math.random() * 2) * 90; })
      .font("Impact")
      .fontSize(function(d) { return d.size; })
      .on("end", draw)
      .start();

  function draw(words) {
      d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", 300)
        .attr("height", 300)
      .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(150,150)")
      .selectAll("text")
        .data(words)
      .enter().append("text")
        .style("font-size", function(d) { return d.size + "px"; })
        .style("font-family", "Impact")
        .style("fill", function(d, i) { return fill(i); })
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("transform", function(d) {

          return "translate(" + [d.x, d.y] + ")rotate(" + d.rotate + ")";
        })
        .text(function(d) { return d.text; });
  }
  function drawUpdate(words){
   d3.layout.cloud().size([500, 500])
      .words(words)
      .padding(5)
      .rotate(function() { return ~~(Math.random() * 2) * 90; })
      .font("Impact")
      .fontSize(function(d) { return d.size; })
      .start();


      d3.select("svg")
      .selectAll("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(150,150)")
      .selectAll("text")
        .data(words).enter().append("text")
        .style("font-size", function(d) { return d.size + "px"; })
        .style("font-family", "Impact")
        .style("fill", function(d, i) { return fill(i); })

        .attr("transform", function(d) {

          return "translate(" + [d.x, d.y] + ")rotate(" + d.rotate + ")";
        })
        .text(function(d) { return d.text; });



  }

  setInterval(function () { 
        var d_new = data;
        d_new.push({word:randomWord(),weight:randomWeight()});

         drawUpdate(d_new.map(function(d) {
        return {text: d.word, size: d.weight};
      }));
      }, 1500);

  function randomWord() {
          var text = "";
          var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

          for( var i=0; i < 5; i++ )
              text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));

          return text;
      }
      function randomWeight(){
        var r = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
        return r;
      }
</script>
```

Comment: well have you notice something .. text get overlap each other it means layout is not updating , yes new word is getting added because it's d3 part but the original cloud layout is not updated .... if it will update text will avoid overlapping

Comment: @Aakash - I am able to get the words and word attributes, such as `font-"Impact"`, `hasText-true` (console.log output), but how do I then render/generate the SVG necessary to render these to the frontend? I see with the `broswerify` example, you can just append these to an element, but I am using `Node JS`